# Logarithm of the dot product of two vectors.

Tags: logarithms

Let $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ be two vectors and $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$ be their dot product. 
My question is that how to take the logarithm of the dot product, that is,
how do we find $\log(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$?

Comment: It is like saying that how to simplify the factorial of $(a+b)!$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: And dot product of two vectors is not equivalent to the product of to numbers, so you cannot write your expression as $\log{\vec{u}}+\log{\vec{v}}$.

Comment: can you use the definition of dot product

Comment: You can simplify it farthest to, $\log{|a|}+\log{|b|}+\log{\cos\theta}$

Comment: See this for non-elementary approach-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix